# awk script to list files with specified filenames

Tags: linux, awk, scripting, regular-expression, filenames

I am trying to write an `awk` script which have string as a pattern and want to list all file in a directory which have this pattern in their name. but I don't know how to tell my `awk` function to read all filenames in a directory(and `find` command won't help me in this case). my input pattern is a date in `YYYYMMDD` format and my file starts with a format like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

This is what I am trying to do in my `.awk` file:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
Directory="history/"

date="20180522"

validDate=substr(date,0,4)"-"substr(date,5,2)"-"substr(date,7,2)
printf Directory
system("find $Directory -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \"validDate*\" ") 
}
```

The problem is how to tell `system` get write values from `$Directory` and `$validDate` defined before.

Comment: I don't see why `find` isn't an option. You can easily `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*pattern\*` which will return all files in the current directory with the pattern in their names.

Comment: @NasirRiley thanks. you are right it seems to be ok and it does not have any error or warning but it cant find files in specified directory while those are there. Is there any problem with how I give the Directory argument to find?

Comment: Is `history` the directory that contains the files?

Comment: @NasirRiley yes. That is the Directory

Comment: You cannot use string interpolation (`"....$Directory..."`) in awk. Use string concatenation: `system("find " Directory " -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \"validDate*\" ")`.

Comment: @Amadan thanks for your reply. that helped me. :) can you please post your answer so other people can use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of search and helps from friends I found solution. As a friend helped with my mistake in comments I post this so others can use that. 
As [Amadan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/60565/amadan) says :

> You cannot use string interpolation `("....$Directory...")` in `awk`. Use string concatenation: 
>   `system("find " Directory " -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \"validDate*\" ")`

So I updated my script with :

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
Directory="history/"

date="20180522"

validDate=substr(date,0,4)"-"substr(date,5,2)"-"substr(date,7,2)
printf Directory
system("find " $Directory " -maxdepth 1 -type f -name " validDate"*") 
}
```

And it works! :) :)

Comment: To be totally honest, I can't see why you use awk at all here.

Comment: @Kusalananda That's because of an old system I'm working with. It's not my choice at all. I have to do that this way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` in one of three ways:

From inside of the `history` directory itself:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*pattern\*
```

From the directory just above that contains the `history` directory

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*pattern\*
```

From anywhere:

```
find /path/to/history -maxdepth 1 -type f -name \*pattern\*
```

You can pass the input to the `find` command as the pattern that you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for your response. I use the third option. when I run that directly in a terminal it works. but when I put this find into a .awk file it returns nothing. can you help me with this?

Comment: If you want to use it in a script then change the shebang at the top of your script. Change `#! /usr/bin/awk -f` to `#!/bin/bash`. The shebang is telling your script which shell to use so instead of using the path to the command, you use the path to the shell which is `/bin/bash`.

Comment: if I use bash then the script wont recognize other functions defined in awk. that's why i've used  ' #! /usr/bin/awk -f '.it doesn't seem to solve m problem

Comment: If use are using the same awk in the `bash` shell then I don't see why anything with `awk` or any other command won't work. If you just pass the input to the `find` command then there's no reason to use `awk` anyway.

Comment: yeah. it seems to be ok. I think maybe the problem is how to show output. how can I see out put . still it does show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to use `awk` to get the date from the user in `YYYYMMDD` format and then to turn this into the `YYYY-MM-DD` format to do a file search.

`awk` is more suited for stream parsing than for interactive programming. It also does not know how to iterate through a file hierarchy.

Here's a proposal that instead uses a shell script to read the data from the user, and which uses `find` to look for the files:

```
#!/bin/sh

thedate="$1"

if [ -z "$thedate" ]; then
    printf 'Enter year (YYYY): ' >&2
    read theyear
    printf 'Enter month  (MM): ' >&2
    read themonth
    printf 'Enter day    (DD): ' >&2
    read theday

    thedate="$theyear-$themonth-$theday"
fi

find /path/to/history -type f -name "*$thedate*"
```

This script may be run with or without command line arguments.  If the script detects that it was used with a command line argument, it will assume that it is a date string in the correct format and use that as is to look for the files.

Comment: thanks for your response. I will get the date from another function call. I take it from user now for just test. As I have said before my problem is the find command. it seems it cannot see the directory files. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Nahid Do update your question with further information about what the format of your filenames is.  At the moment, you only say that you are looking for files that contains date in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, which is what the `find` command in my answer does. You should obviously change the directory path at the start of that command...